# How to Access Source Code or Definitions of Inbuilt Functions in Mule 4 DataWeave?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I've primarily relied on custom modules and functions I've created for specific needs. However, I've also been utilizing a number of inbuilt functions provided by Mule in DataWeave, such as the upper function, which returns the provided string in uppercase characters, with the syntax upper(text: String): String.

how does Mule implement this? Or where could I find the source code of this function?

Comment: The question is not clear. What are you trying to ask? Why do you need the source for the built in functions? Curiosity or you are trying to resolve an issue?

Comment: Aled its just curiosity to understand and get deep knowledge. how exactly behind the scene its happening

Comment: DataWeave is not open source at this time so its code is not publicly available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For see implementations of the DataWeave functions in Anypoint studio, use [CTRL] button and LMB click at the function name.

[picture of Set Payload where to CTRL and LMB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HbN9.png)

For example, upper:

```
/**
* Returns the provided string in uppercase characters.
*
* === Parameters
*
* [%header, cols="1,3"]
* |===
* | Name   | Description
* | `text` | The string to convert to uppercase.
* |===
*
* === Example
*
* This example converts lowercase characters to uppercase.
*
* ==== Source
*
* [source,DataWeave,linenums]
* ----
* %dw 2.0
* output application/json
* ---
* { "name" : upper("mulesoft") }
* ----
*
* ==== Output
*
* [source,JSON,linenums]
* ----
* { "name": "MULESOFT" }
* ----
**/
fun upper(text: String): String = native("system::StringUpperFunctionValue")
```

You can see `native("system::StringUpperFunctionValue")`. The function `native` means that the implementation is in jar or class files. Specifically, `system::StringUpperFunctionValue` `StringUpperFunctionValue.class` is located in the maven package groupId `org.mule.weave` artifactId `runtime`.

Comment: Those classes are probably developed in Scala like the rest of DataWeave.

Comment: how to identify which class file it is for required function as there are multiple files and nothing named with function or StringUpperFunctionValue.please let me know or add a screen shot of that

Comment: @Михаил Сидоренко i found it inside the repo with path C:\Users\anurag\.m2\repository\org\mule\weave\core-modules\2.4.0-20220824.jar and when i unzipped this jar i found a class file file that i decomplied (runtime-2.4.0-20220824\org\mule\weave\v2\runtime\core\functions\stringops\StringUpperFunctionValue.class)
which is developed in scala. to understand this more i have to explore. any way  got the idea

Comment: @AnuragSharma Unfortunately, I don’t know the full terms of the DataWeave license, so just in case I refrained from describing how MuleSoft class files are structured and I’m afraid to call for any action.  I found the files `StringUpperFunctionValue.class` and `StringUpperFunctionValue$.class` by scanning the entire `.m2` folder.